# Where does Vagrant download its .box files to?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

What happens to the .box file after the following command is executed?

```
vagrant box add lucid32 http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box
```

I can't find the `lucid32.box` file on the file system after download has completed.

Comment: I think I'm completely missing your point because the first thing that pops into my mind is `sudo find / -name lucid32.box`.

Comment: exactly what I did, but I must be missing something as I could not find `lucid32.box` using this exact command...

Comment: Perhaps it does not exist with that name. Wild card searches such as `*.box` maybe? (BTW, wouldn't the extension be `.vbox`?)

Comment: Yes you are right. The search should be for `*.vbox` and `not *.box`. Mystery solved. :-)  Would you like to key in an answer so I could accept it? Thx!

Comment: @CalvinCheng: I think you're mistaken about it being just a .vbox image in a tar archive.   It is indeed a tar archive, but it contains files like box-disk1.vmdk, box.ovf, and Vagrantfile.  I don't know exactly how those are used to create the files that VirtualBox uses, but if you open VB's .vbox file you'll see it is just XML.  I'm assuming Vagrant transforms its files (also a binary and XML file, plus Vagrantfile) into the XML and binary files used by VirtualBox.  If you open the binary files, however, you'll see they're different, so it's not a simple matter of untarring and renaming.

Comment: It's silly that vagrant STILL does not document what `vagrant box add foo` does.

Comment: @Cheeso Given Vagrant is written in ruby, you can get a good idea on what the command does from the box_add.rb file. On my (Mac 10.9.5) system it's located in `/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb`

Answer (score 433, accepted):

As mentioned in [the docs](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/boxes.html), boxes are stored at:

- Mac OS X and Linux: `~/.vagrant.d/boxes`
- Windows: `C:/Users/USERNAME/.vagrant.d/boxes`

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the clarification. I must be blind to have missed out that explanation in the docs.

Comment: @manojlds: see my comment on the question re: the .vbox file.  It's not the VM by itself, it's just an XML file.

Comment: same place on Windows OS?

Comment: You can also use the env var VAGRANT_HOME to specify the location of .vagrant.d, as in VAGRANT_HOME=D:\.vagrant.d (Yes, it works in Windows too).

Comment: in the `C:\Users\{username}\.vagrant.d\boxes` on windows, i found only the `.vmdk` file not the `.box` !!

Comment: ~/.vagrant.d/boxes same for Ubuntu

Comment: Broken link to the docs

Answer (score 86):

On Mac/Linux System, the successfully downloaded boxes are located at:

```
~/.vagrant.d/boxes
```

and unsuccessful boxes are located at:

```
~/.vagrant.d/tmp
```

On Windows systems it is located under the Users folder:

```
C:\Users\%userprofile%\.vagrant.d\boxes
```

Hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  The information about the destination of unsuccessful downloads was useful.

Comment: `~/.vagrant.d/boxes` never stores the .box file itself, just it's contents.  `~/.vagrant/tmp` is used to store the .box temporarily whilst downloading but is deleted upon installation within Vagrant.

Comment: Third line (for Windows) should be `%userprofile%\.vagrant.d\boxes`

Comment: This answer is for the case that you actually care about your hard disk space.

Comment: @kiltek Indeed! I just reclaimed 20 GB just from clearing out the vagrant.d/tmp folder.

Answer (score 51):

To change the Path, you can set a new Path to an Enviroment-Variable named: 
VAGRANT_HOME

```
export VAGRANT_HOME=my/new/path/goes/here/
```

Thats maybe nice if you want to have those vagrant-Images on another HDD.

More Information here in the Documentations: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/environmental-variables.html

Answer (score 20):

The actual `.box` file is deleted by Vagrant once the download and box installation is complete.  As mentioned in other answers, whilst downloading, the .box file is stored as:

```
~/.vagrant.d/tmp/boxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

where the file name is 'box' followed by a 40 byte hexadecimal hash. A temporary file on my system for example, is:

```
~/.vagrant.d/tmp/boxc74a85fe4af3197a744851517c6af4d4959db77f
```

As far as I can tell, this file is never saved with a `*.box` extension, which explains why the searches above failed to locate it.  There are two ways to retrieve the actual box file:

1. **Download the .box file from vagrantcloud.com**

   1. Find the box you're interested in on [the atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search).  For example, 
      https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20150530.0.1
   2. Replace the domain name with `vagrantcloud.com`.  So https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20150530.0.1
      becomes https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20150530.0.1/providers/virtualbox.box.
   3. Add `/providers/virtualbox.box` to the end of that URL.  So  https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20150530.0.1 becomes https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20150530.0.1/providers/virtualbox.box
   4. Save the .box file
   5. Use the .box as you wish, for example, hosting it yourself and pointing `config.vm.box_url` to the URL. **OR**
2. **Get the .box directly from Vagrant**

   This requires you to modify the ruby source to prevent Vagrant from deleting the box after successful download.

   1. Locate the box_add.rb file in your Vagrant installation directory.  On my system it's located at `/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb`
   2. Find the box_add function.  Within the `box_add` function, there is a block that reads:

      > ensure
      >     # Make sure we delete the temporary file after we add it,
      >     # unless we were interrupted, in which case we keep it around
      >     # so we can resume the download later.
      >     if !@download_interrupted
      >       @logger.debug("Deleting temporary box: #{box_url}")
      >       begin
      >         box_url.delete if box_url
      >       rescue Errno::ENOENT
      >         # Not a big deal, the temp file may not actually exist
      >       end
      >     end
   3. Comment this block out.
   4. Add another box using `vagrant add box <boxname>`.
   5. Wait for it to download.
      You can watch it save in the `~/.vagrant.d/tmp/` directory as a `boxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` file.
   6. Rename the the file to something more useful. Eg, `mv boxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX trusty64.box`.

## Why would you want this?

For me, this has been useful to retrieve the .box file so it can be hosted on local, fast infrastructure as opposed to downloading from [HashiCorp's Atlas box catalog](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search) or [another box provider](http://www.vagrantbox.es/).

This really should be part of the default Vagrant functionality as it has a very definitive use case.

Comment: is it possible to like, zip or tar the subfolders in the boxes folder to create an installable box file?

Comment: @ThorSummoner Yes, but you may aswell let Vagrant handle it in that case, eg, via the `vagrant package` command: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html.

Answer (score 15):

@Luke Peterson: There's a simpler way to get .box file.

Just go to https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search, search for the box you'd like to download. Notice the URL of the box, e.g:

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/**ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20150530.0.1**

Then you can download this box using URL like this:

https://vagrantcloud.com/**ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20150530.0.1**/providers/virtualbox.box

I tried and successfully download all the boxes I need. Hope that help.

Comment: This is a great find!  Thank you.  ;)

Comment: Link is now broken - need to be replaced with: https://app.vagrantup.com.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows, the location can be found here. I didn't find any documentation on the internet for this, and this wasn't immediately obvious to me:

`C:\Users\\{username}\\.vagrant.d\boxes`

Comment: Does %userprofile%\.vagrant.d\boxes work then? %userprofile% expands to c:\users\{username}

Answer (score 3):

In addition to

```
Mac:
~/.vagrant.d/

Windows:
C:\Users\%userprofile%\.vagrant.d\boxes
```

You have to delete the files in VirtualBox/OtherVMprovider to make a clean start.

Answer (score 0):

On *Windows 10* with *Vagrant 2.2.2*, setting the environment variable `VAGRANT_HOME` will ensure that boxes are downloaded to a subfolder of the folder specified for `VAGRANT_HOME`.

In my case I set `VAGRANT_HOME` to `e:\vagrant_home`, and the boxes get stored under `e:\vagrant_home\boxes`.

This works for me.

That's where the **boxes** are stored. The **virtual machines** are being created in the folder configured in Virtual Box. To set the VirtualBox VM storage folder, go to: `VirtualBox GUI --> File --> Preferences --> General --> Default Machine Folder`.