# Where vagrant .box stores in Linux (Centos7)

Tags: linux, vagrant, vagrantfile

Note: For creating clone of Vagrant Box

I have created vagrant box for centos from atlas.hasicorp. 
`https://atlas.hashicorp.com/matyunin/boxes/centos7'

`[user@localhost vagrant_ssh]$ vagrant init matyunin/centos7' This command creates **VagrantFile** in **vagrant_ssh** directory.

`[user@localhost vagrant_ssh]$ vagrant up --provider virtualbox`. Now this will download this vagrant box.

Now I want to create clone of this vagrant box. I can easy to by doing **transfer the .box file to the other machine, add the box and run vagrant up.** But I am not able to find the location of vagrant box in **Centos 7**. In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28126013/4884941), someone mentioned path for vagrant in Mac/linux is `~/.vagrant.d/boxes`, but I didn't find this path on **Centos7**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box is not stored in the vm but on the host machine, so search for the files on your system

The default path is :

- Mac OS / Linux: ~/.vagrant.d/boxes
- Windows: C:/Users/USERNAME/.vagrant.d/boxes