# vagrant and puppet - function_is_bool error

Tags: vagrant, puppet

We use vagrant to manage  a dev install of one of our products, and find that some of our developers can use our vagrant recipes, and others can't. The people that can't get a fail from puppet:

```
undefined method "function_is_bool" for Scope(Class[Puppet])
```

What could be causing this error, as all devs have tried it from scratch, ensuring that they have a fresh copy of the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For us, we have a custom base box we use, and it's only downloaded once and used for multiple vagrants.

The developers with the problem had an old version of this base box, and once we removed it and got it fresh, the problem went away.

You can find out what version of base boxes you have by running:

`$ vagrant box list`

Then to remove the bad box, run something like this:

`$ vagrant box remove OUR-BAD-BOX-NAME`

Note if removing the box this way doesn't work, you can always remove it manually by deleting the box itself, [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10226134/26510)