# Vagrant : ENOSPC completely block box

Tags: python, vagrant, virtual-machine

I'm following this tutorial : https://docs.pybossa.com/installation/vagrant/
But as I don't have rights on my windows 7 machine I used my VM to deploy vagrant & co. Once I finally got it working, a started the installation of requirements and the box is completely stuck.

Host (VM) : Linux ipf7028 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 29 14:49:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Vagrant provider : default,  VirtualBox
Once box finally started, I had to execute in ssh `python run.py` but I had an error, as I'm a newbie in python I just installed pip and did `pip install -r requirements.txt` that was provided.
And after some downloads, global crash with following error :

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:836:in `initialize': No space left on device @ rb_sysopen - /root/.vagrant.d/perm_test_YCKSPNYMOHEIFYNPVJKQYEMPHUIXGQUN (Errno::ENOSPC)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:836:in `open'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:836:in `open'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:836:in `setup_home_path'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:135:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/bin/vagrant:145:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/bin/vagrant:145:in `<main>'
```

It is obviously something with disk space but I can't figure out where... Plus I do not have any access on the vagrant box, no command line are working... destroy, halt, ssh, status everything end up with the same error output.

The provided VagrantFile :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# PyBossa Vagrantfile

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

# Ansible install script for Ubuntu
$ansible_install_script = <<SCRIPT
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo Check if Ansible existing...
if ! which ansible >/dev/null; then
  echo update package index files...
  apt-get update -qq
  echo install Ansible...
  apt-get install -qq ansible
fi
SCRIPT

$ansible_local_provisioning_script = <<SCRIPT
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
echo PyBossa provisioning with Ansible...
ansible-playbook -u vagrant /vagrant/provisioning/playbook.yml -i /vagrant/provisioning/ansible_hosts -c local
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 1024
  end
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 5000, guest: 5000
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 5001, guest: 5001
  # turn off warning message `stdin: is not a tty error`
  config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"
  # be sure that there  is Ansible for local provisioning
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $ansible_install_script
  # do the final Ansible local provisioning
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $ansible_local_provisioning_script
end
```

The box was supposed to work without any problems, even `virtualenv` was supposed to handle some problems about requirements... (never used before).
I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this [Where does Vagrant download its .box files to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155708/where-does-vagrant-download-its-box-files-to?noredirect=1&lq=1) I just destroy the previous vargant environment and changed its location (setting VAGRANT_HOME) where I have more space.
Im running into other issues now, but this thread is over.